# Finding recurrent words in dictionary keys and grouping the keys according to it

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to perform attribute extraction task from ecommerce data (possibly via LSTM). My data consists of product descriptions and keywords, like:

```
description = "cat food tuna fish 200 gram"

keywords = {"type of pet": "cat", "taste" : "tuna fish", "weight" : "200 gram"}
```

I want to use the keys from the keywords' dictionary above as future labels for learning. My problem is that after extracting all the keywords, I have many keys which are semantically similar and have recurrent words, which results in about 2000 labels. For example: "color of dress", "color of chair", "main color", "weight", "net weight", "type of material", "type of wood", etc.

I want to reduce the number of labels by grouping the keys that have the same word: if the dictionary key has "color" in it, group it under "color", and assign all the values of these keys to the new/substitute key, "color".

At the moment, my dictionary looks like:

```
{"type of material": ["wood", "metal", "rayon"....], "type of 
  fabric": ["cotton", "lycra"....]}
```

I want it to look like:

```
{"type": ["wood", "metal", "rayon", "cotton", "lycra"]}
```

What would be the best way to do this and is this a reasonable way to approach labeling entities for LSTM?

Comment: Your code snippets gives an error (`dicts` inside of an `set`). Did you mean to put them in a `list`?

Comment: @ikkuh sorry about that, I typed an extra set of {} in the post. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify keywords to look for, then use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with iteration:

```
d = {"type of material": ["wood", "metal", "rayon"],
     "type of fabric": ["cotton", "lycra"],
     "color of chair": ["brown", "black"],
     "color of dress": ["read", "yellow"]}

from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)

keywords = ['type', 'color']

for k, v in d.items():
    for word in keywords:
        if word in k:
            dd[word].extend(v)
            break
```

Note priority is given to the first keyword match found, and each value in `d` is linked to a maximum of one key in the result:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'color': ['brown', 'black', 'read', 'yellow'],
             'type': ['wood', 'metal', 'rayon', 'cotton', 'lycra']})
```

If you need to extract *all possible keywords* (this would, in this case, include `of`, `material`, etc), you can do so via `str.split`:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    for akey in k.split():
        dd[akey].extend(v)
```

Comment: The problem is that I have 2000 keys, and I would rather have it search for recurrent words in the keys and classify them according to that.

Comment: As far as I can see, a loop is unavoidable for `search for recurrent words`. You can investigate trie-based algorithms (e.g. [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm)) via 3rd party libraries, probably non-trivial. But there's no inbuilt searcher for what you want.

Comment: I agree that loops are unavoidable in this case. What I was referring to is "keywords = ['type', 'color']" - is there any way to not specify the keywords, but instead extract them while iterating through the keys?